# What's wrong with my approach to solving this integral via trigonometric substitution?

Tags: calculus, substitution, trigonometric-integrals

(I'm sorry, I've spent the last hour trying to figure out Latex, but nothing's working. I'm just going to paste my work as I've written it in pencil.)

I'm trying to solve this equation:
[Integral from problem set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHfhp.png)

And while certain online solvers give me a certain trigonometric solution, I've tried a different one that I think should work. My own work's below:
[solution, part 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SsNnj.png)
[solution, part 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OJRqo.png)

That said, I seem to not be getting the right answer. This is what integral-calculator.com gives me:
[calculator's solution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzDgR.png)

And having graphed both in Desmos, both equations look quite different when graphed for a = b = 1:
[desmos graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ3ys.png)

Could someone help me figure out what I'm missing here? Thank you!

Comment: you have $x=\frac{b}{a}\tan(\theta)$, which is fine, but you failed to replace $dx$ with $\frac{b}{a}\sec^2(\theta)d\theta$ in your solutions

Comment: Welcome. LaTeX is a bit of a job to figure out but it does repay itself with dividends! You may generally find that questions that do not require clicking into a bunch of third-party links are answered more quickly. But I really appreciate the effort that has gone into wrestling with this problem.